# How to make my function return [native code]

Tags: javascript

When I enter toString on the chrome console the following appears:

```
function toString() { [native code] }
```

How can I hide code from my function as well as native functions?

Comment: You would have to compile your own version of Chrome / Firefox.. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard this is the way browsers work.
You can obfuscate the code.

It will be harder to read but it can be understand if the programmer have enough time.

You can obfuscate the code here:

https://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide your function as well you just need to override the toString() function like this

```
function sum(x,y){ return x+y;}
sum.toString = function (){ return"[any text]";};
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You are seeing there [native code] because this function code is not written in Javascript. If you want that no one underestands your code, I think it would be enough minifing, uglifing and concating your js files.

Uglify online for testing: https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/